# Failed to load files from gems installled with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets, spine.js

I'm developing an webapplication with rails 4 and spine js as the frontend mvc framework.
With gem 'spine-rails' installed, I ran the command

> rails g spine:new

And in the app folder generated, the index.js.coffee file load some 3rd party assets.

```
#= require json2
#= require jquery
#= require spine
#= require spine/manager
#= require spine/ajax
#= require spine/route

#= require_tree ./lib
#= require_self
#= require_tree ./models
#= require_tree ./controllers
#= require_tree ./views

class Frontend extends Spine.Controller
  constructor: ->
    super

    # Initialize controllers:
    #  @append(@items = new Frontend.Items)
    #  ...

    Spine.Route.setup()    

window.Frontend = Frontend
```

when running the server, here comes an error that

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound at /
couldn't find file 'json2' (in /Users/edward/git/beta-cafe/app/assets/javascripts/frontend/index.js.coffee:1)
```

It seems that there js files like json2, spine, spine/ajax, are loaded in the gem folder.But Rails fails to load them.

Any solutions? :)

Comment: Try to require json2 in config/application.rb and remove it from index.js.coffee.

Answer (score 0):

Add `gem 'json2-rails'` to your gemfile.

This solved the same issue for  me. It shouldn't be necessary, though, because the spine-rails  has that gem as a dependency.

#### Edit

After posting this answer, I confirmed my answer when I happened to look at the [spine-rails github repo](https://github.com/spine/spine-rails) while working on another project. It says:

> In your Gemfile, add the following lines:
>
> gem "json2-rails"
>
> gem "spine-rails"

So you must include the json2-rails gem in your gemfile.